# v-for: Array element and destructuring of properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When working with an array of objects, is it possible in a `v-for`-loop to assign the current object to a variable and destruct its properties at the same time? Something like this:

```
<div v-for="(person = {name, age}, index) in persons">
```

Ultimately I'm looking for a way to use e.g. both the whole `person` object and its properties in a template.

Comment: why not using `person.name` and `person.age` in template, instead of destructuring the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do both.

But, you can destructure, i.e.

```js
<div v-for="({name, age}, index) in persons">
```

You could then just access the correct element with the index: `persons[index]`.

---

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript",
        done: false
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue",
        done: false
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        done: true
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome",
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(index) {
      this.todos[index].done = !this.todos[index].done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="({text, done}, i) in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(i)"
          v-bind:checked="done">

        <del v-if="done">
          {{ text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ text }}
        </span>
        
        {{todos[i]}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```